# Реализация видео чата

Tags: веб-программирование, php, видео, javascript, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие нибудь статьи, а лучше готовые скрипты или движки, для реализации видео чата на сайте.

Answer (score 2):

[VideoChatBuilder 3.0 is now available now made with open source red5 rtmp server, flex, as3 : enter the avatr chat now](http://www.videochatbuilder.com).

Comment: Спасибо. А нету ли каких нибудь статей на русском языке, не обязательно об этом движке, а может просто о разработке видео чата?( Может есть что нибудь типа "пишем видео чат"?)